# Непонятные изображения (ракета, молния ...) в HTML коде?

Tags: html, css

В HTML коде увидел непонятные  изображения откуда они берутся, как можно их использовать
?

Comment: Очень похоже что подключён особый шрифт на сайте, проверьте computed элемента со спецсимволами в консоли (прим. http://joxi.ru/8AnbqWWizXYBPA )

Comment: это просто эмодзи, лол, смайлики в тексте

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это спецсимволы (emoji) - скопируйте их и вставьте в код.

https://unicode.org/emoji/charts-12.0/full-emoji-list.html

https://getemoji.com/

```html
<button>⚽️</button>
```

---

[Ответ с использованием emoji](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/982787/188366)

---

[Язык программирования на основе emoji](https://www.emojicode.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Такие смаайлики можно добавить использованием десятичных HTML кодов 😂 😂(&#x1f602) такие спецсимволы в DevTools (html) отображаются как обычные смайлики хотя и пишутся как текст, [здесь](https://modx-gu.ru/html-codes/emoji) их можно посмотреть